# python-like string indexing in C++

Tags: c++, python, string

Is there any (possibly, using a macros) way to get a substring of a string using python-like expression f(i:j)? Or, more specifically, resolve i:j expression into pair of indices i and j? Any ideas?

EDIT: Yes, I need :. Or ;. Basically, something that simple function or macros can't do.
Just want to see if it is possible or not.

EDIT: Basically, I want to see if it is widely applicable. For arrays as well, maybe. So the question is more of a "Can I turn i:j to i j", I guess. Doesn't matter is these are std:strings or c-strings.

Comment: Are you very specific about the colon (:) in between `i` and `j`? Can you use comma (,)?

Comment: If you are in C++, write C++ code. Don't look for ways to make your C++ look like python.

Comment: The Python-like expression would be `f[i:j]`. Regardless of whether it's possible and/or good, is there are a reason why you want round brackets?

Comment: Are you using c-strings or `std::string`?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't abuse macros to do this in C++, that's a bad path down which to go.

Comment: No, absolutely no way whatsoever.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hate myself for answering, but ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define f(x) substr(true?x, false?x)

int main () {
  std::string s = "Hello, world";
  std::string y = s.f(1:4);
  std::cout << y << "\n";
}
```

Warning: I am a hiring manager. If I ever discover that you use this technique, I will **never** hire you.

Comment: That's too brilliant to not upvote, even if it should never be used.

Comment: Maybe you should include a disclaimer at the end

Comment: That is great, thank you:)
#define g(x) f(0 x)
also allows g(:3) and other cool stuff:)

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The output is "ello".  In Python, the output for the expression s[1:4] would be "ell".